# Flutter / Dart - ToggleButtons how to integrate into my current code

Tags: flutter, dart, togglebutton

I'm new to coding of any sort and now trying to add in ToggleButtons (I think this is the best option for what I need) so that user can select one of 3 options, but struggling to know how to integrate ToggleButtons into my current code? I have a screen shot of my current app screen and how I would like it to look with ToggleButtons.  Please can anyone help? Thank you

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Help with diabetic dosage for a meal!';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  Color _fillColor = Colors.white;
  TextEditingController numR1C1controller =
      TextEditingController(); //Changed name of the texteditingcontroller as Row as R and Column as C
  TextEditingController numR1C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR1C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C3controller = TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";
  String result2 = "0";
  String result3 = "0";

  _calculateR1() {
    if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      double sum = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) -
          double.parse(numR1C2controller.text);
      numR1C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
    }

    if (numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) < 5
            ? Colors.red
            : double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) > 9.1
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.green;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = Colors.white;
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR2() {
    if (numR2C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR2C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR2C1controller.text) /
            double.parse(numR2C2controller.text);
        numR2C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result2 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR3() {
    if (numR3C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR3C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR3C1controller.text) *
            double.parse(numR3C2controller.text);
        numR3C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result3 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                child: Text('Meal Ratio'),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      controller: numR1C1controller,
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Target Level',
                          hintText: 'Enter First Number',
                          fillColor: _fillColor,
                          filled: false),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                          filled: true,
                          labelText: 'Current Level',
                          hintText: 'Enter Second Number',
                          fillColor: _fillColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR1C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                child: Text('Calculations'),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C1controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'One Unit',
                        hintText: 'Enter Third Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Drop by',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fourth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR2C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR3C1controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Meal Carbs',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fifth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR3C2controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Meal Ratio',
                        hintText: 'Enter Sixth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: numR3C3controller,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Result',
                        hintText: '',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to make a list of Maps that keeps track of your buttons,

```
// MAKE LIST OF MAP TO KEEP TRACK OF EACH BUTTONS
List<Map> buttons = [{"name":"BreakFast","active":false},
                   {"name":"Lunch","active":false},
                   {"name":"Tea","active":false},];
```

then make a `function` that handle which button to **select** and **toggle**

```
// TOGGLE BUTTON FUNCTION
toggleButtons(String name){
  for(var i in buttons){
    if(i['name'] == name){
      i['active'] = !i['active'];
    }else{
      i['active'] = false;
    }
  }

  setState((){});
}
```

here is the full code:

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

      void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

      class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
        const MyApp({super.key});

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          const appTitle = 'Help with diabetic dosage for a meal!';
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: appTitle,
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text(appTitle),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                foregroundColor: Colors.black,
              ),
              body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
            ),
          );
        }
      }

      class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
        const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

        @override
        // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
        _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
      }

      class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
        Color _fillColor = Colors.white;
        TextEditingController numR1C1controller =
            TextEditingController(); //Changed name of the texteditingcontroller as Row as R and Column as C
        TextEditingController numR1C2controller = TextEditingController();
        TextEditingController numR1C3controller = TextEditingController();
        TextEditingController numR2C1controller = TextEditingController();
        TextEditingController numR2C2controller = TextEditingController();
        TextEditingController numR2C3controller = TextEditingController();
        TextEditingController numR3C1controller = TextEditingController();
        TextEditingController numR3C2controller = TextEditingController();
        TextEditingController numR3C3controller = TextEditingController();
        String result = "0";
        String result2 = "0";
        String result3 = "0";

        // MAKE LIST OF MAP TO KEEP TRACK OF EACH BUTTONS
        List<Map> buttons = [{"name":"BreakFast","active":false},
                             {"name":"Lunch","active":false},
                             {"name":"Tea","active":false},];

        // YOU CAN SET VARIABLE TO CURRENT MEAL NAME AND CAN CHECK WHETHER IT'S (breakFast) OR NOT
        String? currentMealType;

        // TOGGLE BUTTON FUNCTION
        toggleButtons(String name){
          for(var i in buttons){
            if(i['name'] == name){
              i['active'] = !i['active'];
            }else{
              i['active'] = false;
            }
          }

          setState((){});
        }

        _calculateR1() {
          if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
              numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
            double sum = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) -
                double.parse(numR1C2controller.text);
            numR1C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
            result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
          }

          if (numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
            setState(() {
              _fillColor = double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) < 5
                  ? Colors.red
                  : double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) > 9.1
                      ? Colors.orange
                      : Colors.green;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _fillColor = Colors.white;
            });
          }
        }

        _calculateR2() {
          if (numR2C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
              numR2C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
            setState(() {
              double sum = double.parse(numR2C1controller.text) /
                  double.parse(numR2C2controller.text);
              numR2C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
              result2 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
            });
          }
        }

        _calculateR3() {
          if (numR3C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
              numR3C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
            setState(() {
              double sum = double.parse(numR3C1controller.text) *
                  double.parse(numR3C2controller.text);
              numR3C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
              result3 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
            });
          }
        }

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: Text('Meal Ratio'),
                    ),

                    // HERER IS THE VIEW FOR BUTTONS
                    //******************************

                    Row(children: buttons.map((btn)=>
                     Expanded(child: 
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap:(){
                            toggleButtons(btn['name']);
                          },
                          child:
                              Container(
                        padding:const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        margin:const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10, right: 10),
                        decoration:BoxDecoration(
                          color:btn['active'] ? Colors.red: Colors.white,
                          border: Border.all(color:Colors.grey[300]!)
                        ),
                        child:Text(btn['name'], style:TextStyle(color: btn['active'] ? Colors.white: Colors.black)),
                      ),),)
                    ).toList(),),

                    //******************************

                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            controller: numR1C1controller,
                            onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                            keyboardType:
                                const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                  RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                            ],
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Target Level',
                                hintText: 'Enter First Number',
                                fillColor: _fillColor,
                                filled: false),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                            keyboardType:
                                const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                            controller: numR1C2controller,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                  RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                            ],
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                filled: true,
                                labelText: 'Current Level',
                                hintText: 'Enter Second Number',
                                fillColor: _fillColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                            keyboardType:
                                const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                            controller: numR1C3controller,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                            ],
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Result',
                              hintText: '',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: Text('Calculations'),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                            keyboardType:
                                const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                            controller: numR2C1controller,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                  RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                            ],
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'One Unit',
                              hintText: 'Enter Third Number',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                            keyboardType:
                                const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                            controller: numR2C2controller,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                  RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                            ],
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Drop by',
                              hintText: 'Enter Fourth Number',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                            keyboardType:
                                const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                            controller: numR2C3controller,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                            ],
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Result',
                              hintText: '',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                            keyboardType:
                                const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                            controller: numR3C1controller,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                  RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                            ],
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Meal Carbs',
                              hintText: 'Enter Fifth Number',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                            keyboardType:
                                const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                            controller: numR3C2controller,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                  RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                            ],
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Meal Ratio',
                              hintText: 'Enter Sixth Number',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                            keyboardType:
                                const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                            controller: numR3C3controller,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                            ],
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'Result',
                              hintText: '',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you @Muddassar, that works perfectly. One other thing, is it possible to add  input text boxes (with default numbers already inside - Breakfast 1.0, Lunch 0.6 and Tea 0.55) (allowing numbers only and decimals) into those toggle boxes and whichever one is picked the default number gets transposed into the numR3C2controller ('Meal Carbs') box to be used in the calculation? If that needs posting as a separate question then I'm more than happy to do that? Thanks

Comment: you can create a new question and share the link here I'll answer there.

Comment: Thank you - here is is https://stackoverflow.com/q/74729386/15953708